# Can't ssh to cygwin sshd from remote location

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I have successfully installed sshd on cygwin. I can ssh to it from within my computer and now I am trying to ssh to it from a remote location. I have disabled Windows firewall. Here is the debug data from my connection attempt. I have added the public key of the remote host to the list of authorized_keys in my /home/bruce/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

```
$ ssh -v -i ./test_ssh/id_dsa bruce@x.x.x.x
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ./test_ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'x.x.x.x' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /u/bruce/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: ./test_ssh/id_dsa
Connection closed by x.x.x.x
```

It seems that cygwin sshd is not accepting my public key. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these to narrow down the problem:

- Try connecting without a key (i.e. with a different account, or with the key temporarily moved out of the way)
- Try connecting from the local host using that key

There is a chance that there is a bug in the version of `sshd` you are running.

Comment: I tried the first option. I am able to connect without the key. Thanks! Any ideas on how I can fix the bug?

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions on authorized_keys.  It cannot be writeable by either group or other.